# Change constant values when building a release edition

Tags: android, eclipse, build-process, release-mode, debug-mode

I'm developing in eclipse using ADT for android.
In my application I have some constants which help me to to debug my app easily.
As an example I have:
`public static final boolean DEBUG_TOAST_LOGS = true;`
which help me to toast some logs on the screen.
Each time I intend to build a release, I have to go through my 
constants and set their values to what is appropriate for the release edition, which is somehow painful.
Now what I want is a way to build my app, using two configurations: one for **debug mode** and the other for **release mode**. The **release mode** should set my constants to the appropriate values. How cant I  do that? What's your suggestion? What's the best way to accomplish my need?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if you are using [Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) as your build system. If you do, you can set build-type specific resources, e.g. a boolean `debug` value will be `true` for debug build type, and false for release build type.

**build.gradle**

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resValue "bool", "debug", "true"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            resValue "bool", "debug", "false"
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**Application.java**

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.debug)) {
            ... // debug logic here
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

@hidro's solution is fine, but requires an unnecessary `getResources()...` call each time you want to access the value.

There's another possibility :

**build.gradle**

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_TOAST_LOGS", "true"
    }

    release {
      buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_TOAST_LOGS", "false"
    }
}
```

}

Then,in your code, you can write :

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG_TOAST_LOGS) {
  // ... enjoy your toasts ...
}
```